# Description and title are not changing in posting custom action using opengraph api

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

My meta tags are in correct format
my code is working fine. the problem is that when i change the description and title  and then post action. i still got the old title and description in post. why it is showing old description and title. is it bug in facebook open graph api? please reply

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# site: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/site#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="7777777777777" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="site:deal" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.site.com/deal_success.php" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="war" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="http://site.com/images/logo.png" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="ola ola ola ola"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="site.com"/>



function downloadCoupon(url)
{   

                FB.api(
                '/me/winery-site:object',
                'post',
                { deal: 'http://www.site.com/page.php' },
                function(response) {
                    //alert(response);
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                       console.log(response.error);
                      alert('Earror occured'); return;
                        document.location=url;
                   } else {

                      alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                       return;
                        document.location=url;
                   }
                }); 


}
```

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say? How long after changing the tags is the old value persisting? It should clear the cache after approx 24 hours

Comment: i got the answer. we should hit url by linter after changing anything other wise we will post the old content

Comment: Then add that as a question and accept is so other people that make the same mistake can get help